# Visual SVNServer with Trac

Tags: svn

Has anybody upgraded to the latest version of Visual SVNServer and been able to get Trac to continue to work under Win32?  If so what were the magic steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions on the VisualSVN Server website (http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/) and was able to get it working with the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using visual svnserver with GEMINI (www.countersoft.com), works great.